# Saving E-Mails into a Silverlight Application

Tags: silverlight, outlook

We have an Silverlight applications for tracking Sales Leads.  In this application files can be attached to the Sales Leads using the File Open dialog and a file upload module.  This works great.

In a perfect world, the client wants to be able to drag and drop e-mails onto the lead in the silverlight application.  I know that this is a stretch.

I am looking for ingenious ways of getting e-mails from Outlook attached to Leads in our database.

Our best idea to date is to forward the e-mails to a monitored mailbox with the Lead # as part of the subject.  A batch program would convert the e-mail into a PDF and save the PDF and file attachments in the lead specific folder.  This feels a little kludgy because the Lead # is not currently exposed to the customer and requires non-techie users to follow instructions.

Please let me know if you have any better ideas.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Actually, with <del>Silverlight 3</del> Silverlight 4 you should be able to code a Silverlight app to accept a drag-drop straight from Outlook.  Tim Heuer has a good article about it [here](http://timheuer.com/blog/#droptarget).  All you would need is to add a drop target area to the Silverlight app, users would navigate to the correct lead in the app, then drag emails straight from their Outlook to the Silverlight app.

Corrected: That was v4, which is still beta.

Comment: Thanks for the clue.  I will try this out and let you know.

Comment: @BBlake: That drag and drop capability is a Silverlight 4 feature.  Unfortunately, that is not a viable option yet.

Comment: Apologies.  you are correct.  I'm still working with v2 in what I've done and misread which version that was added to.